# Replacement for CROSS_REFERENCES in H2 database 2.x?

Tags: h2

With the 2.x version of the H2 database `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` has been massively rebuilt:

> Between version 1.4.200 and version 2.0.202 there have been considerable changes, such that a simple update is not possible.

Unfortunately, the table `CROSS_REFERENCES` now seems to have disappeared.

In the 1.x version I could read the relationships of the tables from this. There were columns like `PKTABLE_NAME`, `PKCOLUMN_NAME`, `FKTABLE_NAME`, `FKCOLUMN_NAME`, `FK_NAME` and `PK_NAME`.

I have not found this information in any table/view in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` 2.x so far.

Does anyone know how I can get the information which ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` contains information about all constraints defined in your tables. If `CONSTRAINT_TYPE` column contains value `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`, this constraint can be referenced by a referential constraint. Referential (foreign key) constraints have type `REFERENTIAL`.

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` contains links between referential constraints and unique / primary key constraints referenced by them.

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` contains information about columns of primary key, unique, and referential constraints. Please note that multi-column referential constraints may reference unique or primary key constraints with the same sets of columns in any order, so for multi-column referential constraint you need to check both `ORDINAL_POSITION` and `POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT` to determine linked columns properly.

All these tables are standardized in *Part 11: Information and Definition Schemas (SQL/Schemata)* of the SQL Standard, so they are more or less portable across all databases that have standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: Another alternative is to use `DatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys()` and/or `DatabaseMetaData.getExportedKeys()` rather than raw SQL